# How do I know what is currently rendered page using navigator?

Tags: react-native

How do I know what is currently rendered page using navigator? The getCurrentRoutes just returns all the routes in the navigator stack. But I'm looking something like the following which will say exactly which page is currently rendered and shown in the screen.

```
navigator.getCurrentPage();
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out.

```
const curRoutes = navigator.getCurrentRoutes()
curRoutes[curRoutes.length-1];
```